# How to find the corresponds file related to given string?

Tags: string, python-3.x, list

I have a based name as `mcf-z-stacks-03212011_a01_s2` that corresponds to the file name `mcf-z-stacks-03212011_a01_s2_w1248254b0-0193-4e11-8762-62b5d2b86216` (similar the filed `mcf-z-stacks-03212011_a01_s2` but add extra `_w1248254b0-0193-4e11-8762-62b5d2b86216`, where extra is a random string). I am finding the way to find the name `mcf-z-stacks-03212011_a01_s2_w1248254b0-0193-4e11-8762-62b5d2b86216` if I only have input is string `mcf-z-stacks-03212011_a01_s2`. How can I do it in python.

For example, the first list store the name

```
lst1=['mcf-z-stacks-03212011_a01_s2_w1248254b0-0193-4e11-8762-62b5d2b86216', 'mcf-z-stacks-03212011_a01_s1_w1448254b0-0193-4e11-8762-62b5d2b86216', ''mcf-z-stacks-03212011_a03_s1_w2248254b0-0193-4e11-8762-62b5d2b86216']    
input='mcf-z-stacks-03212011_a01_s2'
expect_output='mcf-z-stacks-03212011_a01_s2_w1248254b0-0193-4e11-8762-62b5d2b86216'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `startswith` method to check if start string matches.

```
for x in lst1:
     if x.startswith(input):
        expect_output = x
```